# Is the PHP SESSION variable dependent on ip address?

Tags: php, session, ip

I've got a little website project on which I'd like to implement a login-process. I have a login page, which gets me to a second page on successful login. On the second page I check wether the user is logged in with:

```
if($_SESSION['login']==1) {
Do PHP stuff;
}
```

But when testing with xampp and navigating directly to the second page I am able to fill in the form and perform actions without having logged in first on my first login page.

My question now is (I already know, that by default the SESSION variable lasts for about 24minutes), is the SESSION variable dependent on ip addresses or do I need to worry, that when one user is logged in and does stuff another user, who knows the url to my second page can just go to my second page and do stuff there without logging in properly?

Thanks for your help in advance :-)

Comment: The standard cookie-based session is dependent upon a *nonce token* which is sent to and returned from the client via cookies. I do not know if there are additional restrictions (when checking) or if there are variations that include the IP (eg. combined with nonce) in the token itself - anyway, the session is "safe" assuming that ***only** the client that received the nonce knows about it and can send it back*.

Comment: (I don't think this is a bad question - and it would be interesting to see an indepth explanation of one way or the other and different providers or implementations of such session support.)

Comment: Thank you for your input! Appreciate that, for the moment your response clears my insecurity.

Comment: Some quickly selected links: http://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-fall10/lecture.php?topic=secSession (the session cookie is the "session token"), http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/what-is-the-use-of-a-client-nonce (nonce + advanced context) , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery (malicious site tricking user who is already authenticated)